Is $x>y$ or $x<y$ or $x=y$, or it differs in different situations?
I can't understand the difference between these 2 questions that lead to different answers!
Q1. List $\text{A}$ consists of $x$ numbers, and the sum of all numbers of $\text{A}$ is $52$. List $\text{B}$ consists of $y$
numbers and the sum of all numbers of $\text{B}$ is $47$ and the mean of $\text{A}$ is greater than the mean of $\text{B}$.
The answer of the author of the question:
$$\text{mean A}= \frac{52}{x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \text{mean B} = \frac{47}{y}.$$
$$\text{mean A} > \text{mean B} \implies \frac{52}{x} > \frac{47}{x}  \iff y > \frac{47}{52} x,$$
so
$$\begin{align}
x &= 52, \qquad  y = 48 \\
x &= 52, \qquad  y = 60
\end{align}\qquad.$$
So it is not possible to tell whether $x$ is greater or $y$, it differs in different conditions.
Q2. List $\text{A}$ consists of $x$ numbers, and the sum of all numbers of $\text{A}$ is $63$. List $\text{B}$ consists of $y$
numbers and the sum of all numbers of $\text{B}$ is $75$ and the mean of $\text{A}$ is greater than the mean of $\text{B}$.
The answer of the author of the question:
$$\text{mean A}= \frac{63}{x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \text{mean B} = \frac{75}{y}.$$
$$\text{mean A} > \text{mean B} \implies \frac{63}{x} > \frac{75}{x}  \iff y > \frac{75}{63} x.$$
So, $y$ is greater than $x$.

What is your question?

The difference between two same questions but different answers @Ross Milikan

The are not the same question!  Notice one results in $y > mx; m < 1$ and the other results in $y > mx; m > 1$.  If you have $y > mx$ and $m < 1$ you get $y > mx$ and $mx < x$ but you can't combine the two.  In the second case if $m > 1$ we get $y> mx$ and $mx > x$ and we can combine the two:  $y > mx > x$.

Those are two different situations.
Q1:  Yields that $y$ is GREATER than $\frac {47}{52}x$ and $\frac {47}{52}x$ is LESS that $x$.
We can't compare $y$ and $x$ when the only thing we is that they are both bigger than someting.  If $a > c$ and $b > c$ we can't say anything about whether $a >b, a=b, a< c$.  We could have $a > b > c$ or we could have $a=b > c$.  Or we could have $b> a >c$.
They give the example that if $x=52$ and $y = 48$ we have $y < x$ but $y= 48 > \frac {47}{52}x = \frac {47}{52}\times 52 = 47$.
And they give another example where $x=52$ and $y=60$.  Then $y > x$ but $y=60 > 52 > 47 = \frac {47}{52}\times 52 = \frac {47}{52}x$.
But Q2: yields that $y$ is GREATER than $\frac{63}{75}x$ while $\frac{63}{75}x$ is GREATER (!!!NOT LESS!!!) than $x$.
Here we have $y$ is bigger than something that itself is bigger than $x$.  If $a > c$ and $c > b$ we CAN combine them to get $a > c > b$ and we do know that $a > b$.
(THis is actually a common nightmare.  You are trying to compare $M$ to $a$ and you get something you things is in between, say $W$.  You prove $M > W$ and you think "Great I'm halfway there!".  And then you prove $W < a$ and you think "Great! I'm done" and then you write out what you have as $M > W < a$ and ... you realize all you have is garbage and you haven't gotten anywhere.  Have I ever done that?  You bet I have.)

The similarity is that in both answers,
$$
y > q x\ \ ,
$$
in which $q$ is a fraction (i.e. a rational number).
The difference is that in Question 1, $q$ is a proper fraction (i.e. $q < 1$), but in Question 2, $q>1$.
In Question 2, you can follow these steps:
\begin{equation} 
y > \frac{75}{63} x\ \ .
\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, since $\dfrac{75}{63}>1$ and $x > 0$, we have
\begin{equation} 
\frac{75}{63} x > x\ \ .
\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2} you conclude that
$$
y > x\ \ .
$$
Analogous steps don't apply to Question 1 because $\dfrac{47}{52} \not> 1\,$.
